# Kotlin: How can I avoid code duplication in constructors?

Tags: constructor, duplicates, kotlin, code-duplication

Often I find myself in a situation where I have a superclass that has lots of optional parameters, and those same parameters need to also be optional parameters in its subclasses.

For example, the superclass:

```
abstract class Plugin(val name: String, val version: String = "1.0",
                      val author: String = "", val description: String = "")
```

Extending this class is a pain. Here's an example subclass:

```
abstract class CyclePlugin(name: String, version: String = "1.0", author: String = "",
                       description: String = "", val duration: Int, val durationUnit: TimeUnit
                       = MILLISECONDS) : Plugin(name, version, author, description)
```

**Note:** I will answer this question with my solution. I am in search of a *better* solution.

Comment: Yet another reason to avoid inheritance :) If those parameters are optional why use them in constructor at all? Instead you could just declare regular property `var optionalProperty:String? = "DefaultValue"` in base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like [@miensol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155213/miensol) mentioned, you can define your properties outside of the constructor.

```
abstract class Plugin(val name: String) {

    open val version: String = "1.0"
    open val author: String = ""
    open val description: String = ""

}
```

Then you're able to define `CyclePlugin` with only the necessary `name` parameter:

```
abstract class CyclePlugin(name: String, val duration: Int,
                           val durationUnit: TimeUnit = MILLISECONDS) : Plugin(name)
```

Then for example, you can override some fields for `ExamplePlugin`:

```
class ExamplePlugin : CyclePlugin("Example Plugin", 8, TimeUnit.SECONDS) {

    override val author = "Giovanni"
    override val description = "This is an example plugin"

}
```

Comment: What if `CyclePlugin` is not abstract and can be initialized with those optional parameters?

Comment: i was curious if we can do same with `sealed class` in kotlin

Answer (score 6):

The way I normally solve this problem is by creating a data class to represent the parameters.

```
data class PluginInfo(val name: String, val version: String = "1.0",
                      val author: String = "", val description: String = "")
```

I then take this class as a parameter in the constructors.

```
abstract class Plugin(val info: PluginInfo)

abstract class CyclePlugin(info: PluginInfo, val duration: Int,
                           val durationUnit: TimeUnit = MILLISECONDS) : Plugin(info)
```

Then an example plugin can be implemented like this:

```
class ExamplePlugin : CyclePlugin(PluginInfo("Example Plugin", author = "Jire"), 8, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```